# Chartjs Rendering issue with Brave fingerprinting block

Tags: chart.js

When using Brave default fingerprint block the chart from Chartjs no longer renders properly.

You can try yourself to go to this page with the Brave browser:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/border-radius.html

And then try disabling the fingerprint block clicking on the brave icon inside the address bar and selecting: Allow fingerprinting.

What's going on? What can I do to mitigate the issue?

Example:
[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

As described in this [github issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/6197) brave blocks `3rd-party device recognition` by default since it can be used to fingerprint and thus track you. To solve your issue you either need to allow this, disable fingerprint blocking or use another browser